# break out of two loops without disturbing the if statements after it in python

Tags: python

I'm creating a simple login program. It asks you for a username, then the password. If you type the correct password, you're in, else, you get a genial request to repeat your password. here is the code:

```
while True:
    turns= 5
    turns= turns-1
    print ("Username")
    L_username= input ("")
    print ("Authorising...")
    time.sleep(2)
    if(L_username)==("test@test.test"):
        for x in range (5):
            print ("Please enter the password")
            passwordlogin= input("")
            if passwordlogin == ("beta123"):
                print ("Hello, developer.")
                break
            break
            else:
                print ("Incorrect. You have",turns," more turns")
```

now the thing is, it gives me an error message: incorrect syntax for `else:  print ("incorrect`... I know this is meant an issue because I wrote two 'breaks', the latter out of the for loop... which means it will break the while True loop at the start whether or not I go into the loop... which means the 'else' statement is out of the loop (sorry, I am not the best explainer at these things)... which gives the error message. But I don't understand how I should fix this problem... can anyone help?

I hope you understood me!

Comment: remove the second break, it's not syntactically correct because you wrote it at the same indentation as the if statement (which means the 'else' is syntactically wrong)

Comment: remove the second "break" statement. why are you using loop while you are using while statement, instead you can use condition in while loop itself.

Comment: Thanks for the help, everyone! I know this- I just wanted to ask, how do I break the 'while True' statement in the 'if statement' without causing the problem you mentioned? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be triviallized by using a function and `return`ing from it once you reach that `if` statement.

```py
def func():
    while True:
        turns= 5
        turns= turns-1
        print ("Username")
        L_username= input ("")
        print ("Authorising...")
        time.sleep(2)
        if(L_username)==("test@test.test"):
            for x in range (5):
                print ("Please enter the password")
                passwordlogin= input("")
                if passwordlogin == ("beta123"):
                    print ("Hello, developer.")
                    return
                else:
                    print ("Incorrect. You have",turns," more turns")
```

However, if you insist on not having a function, you can basically have a flag in your code that you set to true inside that `if` block. Before continuing the outer loop, you should check if this flag is set to `True`, if it is, you can safely break.

```py
while True:
    success = False
    turns= 5
    turns= turns-1
    print ("Username")
    L_username= input ("")
    print ("Authorising...")
    time.sleep(2)
    if(L_username)==("test@test.test"):
        for x in range (5):
            print ("Please enter the password")
            passwordlogin= input("")
            if passwordlogin == ("beta123"):
                print ("Hello, developer.")
                success = True
                break
            else:
                print ("Incorrect. You have",turns," more turns")
    if success:
        break
```

Note should be taken for nested loops and such intense nesting for what is essentially a trivial problem. Please try to use a singular loop with your conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have written your concept in my own way. Hope this works for you

```
turns = 5

while turns != 0:
    username = input('Enter Username: ')
    password = input(f'Enter password for {username}: ')

    if username == 'test@test.test' and password == 'beta123':
        print('Hello developer')
        turns = 0    # Breaking while loop if user get access within number of "turns"

    else:
         turns = turns - 1  # Or turns -= 1
         print('Incorrect username or password')
         print(f'You have {turns} turns for gaining access')
```

Comment: Thanks... The issue is, if I carry out the commands that you have written, even if I do get all the info correct, it will make me write the info again

Comment: You are welcome but could not get the other part of your saying.

Comment: so... the 'if passwordlogin == ("beta123"):
                print ("Hello, developer.")
                break
            break' command, as you correctly point out, is incorrect. However, I'm asking you why it still asks me the username if I've written everything out.

Comment: nope it won't ask you to write the info again if your login gets successful once

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap the else and break and change the break's indentation. If the user gets the correct username you want to test the password at most 5 times and then quit

```
while True:
turns= 5
print ("Username")
L_username= input ("")
print ("Authorising...")
time.sleep(2)
if(L_username)==("test@test.test"):
    for x in range (5):
        print ("Please enter the password")
        passwordlogin= input("")
        if passwordlogin == ("beta123"):
            print ("Hello, developer.")
            break
        else:
            turns -= 1
            print ("Incorrect. You have",turns," more turns")
     break
```

So in this case you run the for loop and then break